# MIPS r3000 - Loading data in parallel?

Tags: mips

Given a system that takes 8 cycles to retrieve data from RAM if do something like this:

```
lw t1, 0(t2)   #loading something to t1 from RAM
add t4, t5
add t6, t4
add t1, t4     #using t1 for the first time since loading
```

Would the code execution stall after loading the variablle and calling the first add (line 2), or will it stall the first time I use **t1** (line 4)?

Comment: Depends. Does your CPU implementation have shadow registers and checkpointing to allow precise exceptions during speculative execution?

Comment: Thanks for the input.It is actually the ps1 cpu MIPS "R3000A", I cannot find any information regarding that, so I assume it doesnt have "shadow registers", I read some interviews from devs back in the day saying they were executing some instructions while uncached data was loaded (not only the delay slot) but maybe I misread those

Comment: All (sane) ISAs require *precise exceptions*. If you speculatively execute the instructions after the `lw` without waiting for confirmation that the `lw` will not fault, you might not be able to restore the state of the processor when it *does* fault. Debugging becomes *very* challenging without precise exceptions, as does restoring context after a context switch for multiprocessing. The modern approach would be to have extra registers that keep the previous state of all registers that are modified after the potentially faulting instruction until the fault is certain not to happen.

Comment: so, it could actually not stall until line4 but if the lw faults then you are basically in big trouble?

Comment: You would be in big trouble, if the hardware does not restore the state of the machine to the state as it was when the faulting instruction *should have* executed in sequence. If your CPU is old and simple, the easiest way to ensure precise exceptions was probably used, and that is to stall the pipeline. In principle the hardware could start executing again as soon as it has determined that *the load* cannot fault (which means it would only have to wait for the TLB hit in the fastpath), but it must also be able to handle asynchronous exceptions (external interrupt/timer interrupt) too.